# how work activate function event onclick(or other function) when it is activated from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

Some day ago i'd write for asking what was the problem about  onclick event doesn't activate when i clicked in a specific  area of the browser.  After check a guide i find it the problem end  also the rappresentation of my simply test is trivial, i've known the mechanism for activating a particular function in browser text area. 
Now that work it... i'd want add more detail of my question...what is the mechanism that activate my function from template html to tag `<script></script>`  ?

```
    <h3> Check is palindrome</h3>
        <input type="text" id="input1"  >
        <input type="text" id="input2">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="reload" onclick="myFunction()" value="ricarica">

        <body > 
               <p onclick="check()" id="output" style="line-height: 1000px"> TEST</p>
        </body>

    //WHAT IS THE MECHANISM IN THIS POINT FOR ACTIVATE check()?
 <script>    

    function check() {
        var x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        if(x===y){
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=" E' PALINDROMA "
        }else  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=" NON E' PALINDROMA "";
    }

    function myFunction() {
        location.reload(true);
    }


    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to prevent input clicks from propagating to the event you've attached to body? Also why are your inputs outside the body tag?????

Comment: You know you don't have an element with an id of `text` right? It's called `text1` in your first input

Comment: I mean, basically everything about this code is wrong...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah I agree

Comment: I' want to do compare to word when i'm clicking on the tamplate with the mouse....but the proble is that i'm trying to click on input-text...suddenly the function start....

Comment: OP you need to make your question a bit more clear and format your code a bit better

Comment: `document.getElementById("p1")` != `id="p1 "`...whitespace matters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything about your code is wrong. Like... literally everything. Here's a suggested alternative:

```js
var out = document.getElementById('output');
document.getElementById('input').oninput = function() {
  if( this.value.split('').reverse().join('') === this.value) {
    out.innerHTML = "The input is a palindrome!";
  }
  else {
    out.innerHTML = "The input is not a palindrome...";
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<p id="output">Type something...</p>
```

Comment: I think you're being unfair, surely the HTML is .....oh....is that an input outside of the body tag....I take it back... :)

Comment: i'know is a bad code....but is just an example....anyway your version is surely better!...but i'dont want that

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, move your `check()` function to the `input` field

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onclick="check()">
```

and remove from `body`

```
<body>
```